# Easiest way to calculate an value selected with a constant

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I try to find the easiest way to calculate a variable (here, 1 2 or 3) with a constant, in Angular:

```
<select class="inputDuree" name="duree">
    <option ng-model="subValue" value="1">1 mois</option>
    <option ng-model="subValue" value="2">2 mois</option>
    <option ng-model="subValue" value="3">3 mois</option>
</select>

<p class="total-price">{{'subValue' * 1.99}}</p>
```

This doesn't work (logic...), I don't know if I've to rework that in the back or if an magic property in Angular can do the job. I've found some issues with $scope but I don't think it's the easiest way.

Many thanks, have a nice day !

Comment: Add `ng-model` to `select` element instead of `option`

Comment: and initialize your model value otherwise you will ran for a NaN issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup

```
<select class="inputDuree" name="duree" ng-model="obj.subValue>
    <option value="1">1 mois</option>
    <option value="2">2 mois</option>
    <option value="3">3 mois</option>
</select>

<p class="total-price">{{obj.subValue * 1.99}}</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.obj = {
    subValue: 0
};
```